# validate date - problem php

Tags: php, validation, date

i am trying this code to validate a date but i get false.
what is the reason of that?

```
function validate_age($form) {
        $str = "1977/03/27";

        $stamp = strtotime( $str );

        if (!is_numeric($stamp)) {
            echo ("nop");
            return FALSE;
        }

        $year  = date( 'Y', $stamp );
        $month = date( 'm', $stamp );
        $day   = date( 'd', $stamp );


        if (checkdate($year, $month, $day)){
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE; //stops here
}

validate_age($form);
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the order of your arguments

```
checkdate($month, $day, $year);
```

It's all wrote in the php official docu: http://it.php.net/checkdate

Comment: i thought the order must be the same that of the date. In this case /Y/M/D. thanks

Comment: nop. didn't solve. this checkdate($month, $day, $year);  doesn't match this format date /Y/M/D

Comment: you can't change the order of the arguments of php built in functions

Answer (score 0):

month supposed to be from 1 to 12 (no zeros in front)

`checkdate($month, $day, $year);` as in `checkdate(3, 27, 1977);` not `checkdate(03, 27, 1977);` so for month you should use `$month = date( 'n', $stamp );`